# django model.objects.filter for loop doesn't loop through all records

Tags: python, django

this weird thing happened to me, I'm trying to loop through a bunch of records I got from database,
the value of `print(next_ghanoons.count())` is 190
but the thing printed in for loop is

`0`
`1`
`2`,...

and `i` goes till 106 and never reaches 190 records
what's wrong with my code

```
@staticmethod
def get_next(obj):
    current_section = obj.id_section
    current_id_book = obj.id_section.id_book.id_book
    next_order = obj.order + 1
    try:
        next_ghanoons = Ghanon.objects.filter(order=next_order)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return None
    print(next_ghanoons.count())
    i = 0
    for ghanoon in next_ghanoons:
        i = i + 1
        print(i)
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve @S Mhm

Comment: So it stops at `2`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Tushortz I'm clearly not looking for printing indexes, I'm supposed to find an id from `next_ghanoons`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no the count of `next_ghanoons` is 190 but it loops to 106 and never prints 107

Comment: Try to remove the line print(next_ghanoons.count()) . Does the get_next(obj) procedure still stops at 160 this time ?